# Virtual manager/KVM: Easily release usb device

Tags: usb, keyboard, virtualization, linux-kvm, qemu

I am using a KVM guest on a Debian system to run Windows. My main use case is playing games. :) I have generally been using the Synergy program to forward my mouse and keyboard to the guest. But the results are somewhat glitchy (mouse/keyboard-wise), particularly when playing games. I get much better results if I use virtual-manager's usb forwarding/redirecting feature. But this creates a problem: if I forward both my keyboard and mouse to the guest, I have no way to get them back. So, I am looking for some means to trigger a release (un-redirecting) of at least one of the two usb devices. This could be a keyboard hotkey or even some other event (plugging-unplugging some third usb device could be an hack-ish option, or I saw that they sell some external usb buttons). I am a programmer, so I could write some code to make this possible, and indeed it seems possible to me (perhaps D-BUS?), particularly the third device option, but was wondering if anyone has any pointers or if anyone has dealt with something like this before.